# CSS3 Child Elements Width Not Respecting Parent Container Width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to keep my ul and li elements that are inside of a div to respect the div's width with margin-left: auto. I am also not wanting ul/li to extend out of the div. I want the ul and li elements to stay inside the div container. From what I have read, this code is correct because I have the child elements contain a width which should be according to div's width.

```
#phonequeue {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 800px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -650px;
}

li {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 1.2 em
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin: 0px 0px 4px 0px;
    background-color #555
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 30%, from(#444), to(#111));
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;

}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

index.html:

```
    <div id="phonequeue"> 
    <ul>
        <li class="avail">
        <span class="pname">John Doe</span>
        <span class="ptime">03:00</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE: Here is a working example. The element width is 430px; when the parent div is 400px;. I would the child elements to center themselves in div and have their width respecting the parents width.** http://jsfiddle.net/FBvQJ/4/

Comment: As I'm not able to replicate some view of the code in question - it's not clear at all what you're actually up to... (...Have you tried to remove `width:100%;` from your LI elements?)

Comment: [This is what I get with your code.](http://jsfiddle.net/FBvQJ/) Please provide the code that has an issue, explain where the issue is, and what problem you're having

Comment: Ok....done. please see update.

Comment: `text-align:center;`?

Comment: Sorry, typo....the element ul/li elements are 438px and not centered in their parent div that is 400px;.

Comment: The 'extra' width is probably from the padding. This can be solved by using the `boxx-sizing:border-box` fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem was with the use of width: 100%

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BuYGt/) and let me know if this answers your question.

This is the updated CSS to solve the overlapping width:

```
phonequeue {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1pt solid green;
}
ul{
    border: 1pt solid red;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 1.2em;
    margin: 0px 0px 4px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1pt solid #ccc;
}
```

I don't think you need to define the full width for each element.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like the text centered in the DIV, remove the width on the LI tag and make the margin:

```
margin: 0px auto 4px auto;
```

That will center the text within the div.

Comment: I removed the width in both ul and li wich made kept from extending past the div. However, it's margin: auto still is not causing it to center horizontally according to the parent div's width. A little confused since I read where I need to specify width in children to make them fill up div's width and center themselves.

Comment: You've told the `<li>`'s to be `display:block`. This automatically makes them the full width of their parent.

Comment: Cool. I still can not get it to center though. the ul->li floats to the right side of the parent div.

Comment: Change the display to display: inline;

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly (which is dubious) I believe you can achieve the centering you require by removing the 100% widths and using text-align:center:

```
li {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 1.2 em;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin: 0px auto 4px auto;
    background-color #555;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 30%, from(#444), to(#111));
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align:center; /* < this (or not, if you don't actually want it centred after all) */
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0; /* < and this */
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBvQJ/7/)

And later, when you decide that you want the time on the right use

```
.ptime {float:right;}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/FBvQJ/9/)

Comment: What if I do not want the text aligned center? I would like the name to the left.

Comment: Actually, it was the padding: 0 in ul{} that fixed this. For learning purposes, why is this?

Comment: Some box-models include the padding in the overall size, some don't. [See here](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).  `box-sizing: border-box` is your friend